# Git usage for multiple local copies

Tags: git

From my remote repository i am cloning a particular branch using

```
git clone <URL> -b <branch_name> --single-branch <local_copy_1> 
git clone <URL> -b <branch_name> --single-branch <local_copy_2>
```

I clone multiple copies of the same branch in my local system.Now how to i do push,fetch,merge or pull w.r.t to each local copies?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want that. Why change the same branch in two different copies and then push to the same branch?

Comment: because 2 people will be working parallelly in the same machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would push it normally, but each repo needs first to synchronize itself with the latest commits pushed on that branch (pushed from the other cloned repo for instance):

```
git pull --rebase
git push
```

Note that with Git 2.5 (released next week), you will be able to have multiple working tree (meaning multiple checked out branches, including the same one) for *one* cloned repo.
See "[Multiple working directories with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)".